# Solve congruence with primitive root

Tags: number-theory, congruences, primitive-roots

I am seeking the solution to the congruence

$$
29x^{33} \equiv 27\  \text{(mod 11)}
$$

Primitive root is 2 and $ord_{11} (2) =10$. Then I got

[image]

so the equation can be field:

$$
lnd_2(29) + 33 lnd_2(x) \equiv lnd2(27)\  \text{(mod 10)}
$$

Since $$lnd_a(rs) \equiv lnd_ar + lnd_as \ \text{(mod p-1)}$$

However, how to get a prime number 29 to be the product of two numbers??

Comment: $29\equiv 7 \bmod 11$.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much!

Comment: @YangXia: Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: @user88595, one more question is, can I make that 33 in the equation into least residue?

Comment: @lhf Thank you, can I simplify 33 $\equiv$ 0 mod 11??

Comment: @YangXia, no! But you can simplify $33 \bmod 10$.

Comment: @lhf Oh, I think I got a little bit confused, when to mod 11 and when to mod 10?

Comment: @lhf Can you help me to sort this out? I got really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reduce $\bmod 11$:
$$
29x^{33} \equiv 27 \bmod 11 \quad\text{iff}\quad 7x^{33} \equiv 5\bmod 11
$$

Using index calculus gives us
$$
ind(7)+33ind(x)\equiv ind(5) \bmod 10
$$
$$
7+3ind(x)\equiv 4  \bmod 10
$$
$$
3ind(x)\equiv -3  \bmod 10
$$
$$
ind(x)\equiv -1  \bmod 10
$$
so
$
ind(x)=9
$
and $x\equiv 6 \bmod 11$.

Answer (score 2):

Index tables are unneeded since it is $\rm\color{#c00}{easy}$ to take $\,n$'th roots when $\,n\,$ is coprime to $\,p\!-\!1,\,$ e.g.

${\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ 29x^{33}\!\equiv 27\overset{\large\, x^{10}\,\equiv\, 1}\iff\!-4x^3\!\equiv 16\!\!\iff\! x^3\!\equiv -4\!\!\!\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{cube}}\iff\!\! \dfrac{1}x\equiv 2\!\iff\! x \equiv \dfrac{1}2 \equiv \dfrac{12}2 = 6$